# Differing multiple iframes, across multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, iframe

My code stops properly rrunning after the id "greMapTempe"; I assume it's because it cannot find that ID in many of the pages it's plugged into. The iframes I'm loading differ on each page, so I need my script to skip over IDs it cannot find and then proceed to find the next ID. What Can I do to the blow code to make sure all IDs are being checked, even if they're not in the page?

```js
function loadDeferredIframe() {
 var iframe = document.getElementById("greYoutube");
 iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/h7_w43jJ0Ts"

 var iframe = document.getElementById("greMapTempe");
 iframe.src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3330.0372197439724!2d-111.96932568528953!3d33.422273980782116!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zMzPCsDI1JzIwLjIiTiAxMTHCsDU4JzAxLjciVw!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1486774192595"

 var iframe = document.getElementById("greMapCincinnati");
 iframe.src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3086.8059851441258!2d-84.4652936843564!3d39.31532112980541!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88404fb4ec94a687%3A0x915a9a0db6e53917!2sGreat+Room+Escape+Cincinnati!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1541446663243"

 var iframe = document.getElementById("greMapCleveland");
 iframe.src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2992.564362618732!2d-81.627932484311!3d41.405266202849035!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8830e442a6185089%3A0x90787a2298a6c3c2!2sGreat+Room+Escape+Cleveland!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1541446505618"

 var iframe = document.getElementById("greMapColumbus");
 iframe.src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12214.714268930691!2d-82.9792519!3d40.0602736!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xd1a0ee0aa5fb171a!2sGreat+Room+Escape+Columbus!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1541446346773"

 var iframe = document.getElementById("greMapAustin");
 iframe.src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3443.8281848309443!2d-97.71271668471364!3d30.32740461210432!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8644ca3ced1c17f7%3A0x7bd80180add156d1!2sMind+Spark!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1472767173729"

 var iframe = document.getElementById("greMapDallas");
 iframe.src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d13390.834398025358!2d-96.7070997!3d32.9587021!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x897c1a032f856003!2sGreat+Room+Escape+Dallas!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1541446025561"

 var iframe = document.getElementById("greSanAntonio");
 iframe.src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d13900.967422077894!2d-98.4774668!3d29.4217269!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xfee289ea3851e800!2sGreat+Room+Escape+San+Antonio!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1541445639522"
};
window.onload = loadDeferredIframe;
```

Comment: Also only have var once or change the variable name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the element exists before setting the src, or else you'll hit an error and the function's execution will halt.

```js
function loadDeferredIframe() {
    var tryLoadIFrame = function (ID, URL) {
        var iFrame = document.getElementById(ID);
        if (iFrame) {
            iFrame.src = URL;
        }
    }
    tryLoadIFrame("greYoutube", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/h7_w43jJ0Ts");


    tryLoadIFrame("greMapTempe", "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3330.0372197439724!2d-111.96932568528953!3d33.422273980782116!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zMzPCsDI1JzIwLjIiTiAxMTHCsDU4JzAxLjciVw!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1486774192595");


    tryLoadIFrame("greMapCincinnati", "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3086.8059851441258!2d-84.4652936843564!3d39.31532112980541!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88404fb4ec94a687%3A0x915a9a0db6e53917!2sGreat+Room+Escape+Cincinnati!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1541446663243");


    tryLoadIFrame("greMapCleveland", "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2992.564362618732!2d-81.627932484311!3d41.405266202849035!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8830e442a6185089%3A0x90787a2298a6c3c2!2sGreat+Room+Escape+Cleveland!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1541446505618");


    tryLoadIFrame("greMapColumbus", "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12214.714268930691!2d-82.9792519!3d40.0602736!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xd1a0ee0aa5fb171a!2sGreat+Room+Escape+Columbus!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1541446346773");


    tryLoadIFrame("greMapAustin", "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3443.8281848309443!2d-97.71271668471364!3d30.32740461210432!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8644ca3ced1c17f7%3A0x7bd80180add156d1!2sMind+Spark!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1472767173729");


    tryLoadIFrame("greMapDallas", "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d13390.834398025358!2d-96.7070997!3d32.9587021!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x897c1a032f856003!2sGreat+Room+Escape+Dallas!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1541446025561");


    tryLoadIFrame("greSanAntonio", "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d13900.967422077894!2d-98.4774668!3d29.4217269!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xfee289ea3851e800!2sGreat+Room+Escape+San+Antonio!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1541445639522");

};
window.onload = loadDeferredIframe;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of working around this:

### 1- Checking that the variable is not null before changing its `src` attr:

The most basic approach, but probaby the most redundant (unless you use a helper function like @user1538301's answer):

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("greYoutube");
if(iframe) {
    iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/h7_w43jJ0Ts"
}
```

### 2- Using jQuery:

Using jQuery to modify an element by ID (or any selector) will not throw an error, even if there is no match.

```
//will always work, even if there is no match
$("#greYoutube").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/h7_w43jJ0Ts");
```

### 3- Using a selector other than ID:

This third approach has the advantage of being the most **concise** and **maintainbale**, as **you don't need to copy/paste it as many times as you have iframes**.

You can set a specific class name for your iframes to be deferred, as well as a `data-src` attribute (or call it whatever you want) that holds the source that should be the new source for the target iframe. Let me explain:

HTML:

```
<iframe class='defer' src='someSrc' data-src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/h7_w43jJ0Ts'/>
```

JS:

```
//this will not throw an error, because if there is no such element, 
//'iframesToDefer' will be empty and thus we won't enter the loop.
var iframesToDefer = document.getElementsByClassName('defer');
for(var iframe of iframesToDefer) {
    iframe.src = iframe.dataset['src'];
}
```

---

On a side note, **you should not declare a variable more than once** (I am referring to your `iframe` variable).